# c# htmlagility Select specifics nodes depending on the innertext

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have multiple labels inside a div. Those labels have a class which names either "Return" or "Going" like :

```
<div>
    <label class="going"></label>
    <label class="going"></label>
    <label class="going"></label>
    <label class="going"></label>
    <label class="return"></label>
    <label class="return"></label>
    <label class="return"></label>
</div>
```

I want to get two `IEnumerable` of the labels one `going` and one `return`;
something like

```
var going = node.SelectNodes("label").Where(item => item.InnerHtml == "going");
var return= node.SelectNodes("label").Where(item => item.InnerHtml == "return");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use this method:

```
public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
{
    var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
    var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
    return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
}
//use it like this
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("label").Where(_ => _.HasClass("going"))
```